# What's the use of emacs -batch

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to understand the difference between this two lines of code:

emacs **--batch** -l package.el

emacs -l package.el

Thanks a lot. Why -batch is needed here?

Comment: The introduction of the wiki for `batch` webpage may be of some assistance:  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BatchMode

Comment: Thanks, quote that page, 'The command-line option ‘-batch’ causes Emacs to run noninteractively. In this mode, Emacs does not read commands from the terminal, it does not alter the terminal modes, and it does not expect to be outputting to an erasable screen.'

Answer (score 6):

The `-batch` command line option stops Emacs from opening an editor window. This allows you to write scripts in Emacs Lisp, scripts that you otherwise would have used Ruby, Perl, or Python for.

Just out of the hat, an example that use the -batch option is [e2ansi](https://github.com/Lindydancer/e2ansi), a package that allows the `more` and `less` command to render a file with colors using ANSI sequences, based on the syntax highlighting Emacs performs. Clearly, this would not have worked if Emacs would have opened up a window when started.

Comment: All true but the *real* reason for the batch mode, as is well known, is `emacs --batch -l dunnet`.

Comment: Ohh, I've got to try it out, I haven't played an old-school adventure game since the Zork days...